# How to fetch odd columns in oracle

Tags: oracle

How to fetch odd columns in Oracle using a query when number of columns and name of columns are not known?
E.g.:
I need to get output in below format

Column1  column3  column5  column7 
And so on....

Comment: I can't help but wonder what the business use case for this would be.  Or is it a homework assignment meant purely to teach certain techniques?

Comment: There are several additional solutions to this problem, such as 18c polymorphic table functions.  But it's not worth the trouble if this question is merely for homework or curiosity.  When you're asking for something weird it can often help to explain why you're asking for it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the dynamic queries in the procedure as follows:

> ```
> SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ODD_COLUMNS (
>   2      TABLE_NAME_P   IN             VARCHAR2,
>   3      DATAA          OUT            SYS_REFCURSOR
>   4  ) AS
>   5      V_SQL   VARCHAR2(4000);
>   6  BEGIN
>   7      SELECT
>   8          'SELECT '
>   9          ||
>  10              LISTAGG(COLUMN_NAME, ',') WITHIN GROUP(
>  11                  ORDER BY
>  12                      COLUMN_ID
>  13              )
>  14          || ' FROM "'
>  15          || TABLE_NAME_P
>  16          || '"'
>  17      INTO V_SQL
>  18      FROM
>  19          USER_TAB_COLS
>  20      WHERE
>  21          TABLE_NAME = TABLE_NAME_P
>  22          AND MOD(COLUMN_ID, 2) = 1;
>  23
>  24      OPEN DATAA FOR V_SQL;
>  25
>  26  END ODD_COLUMNS;
>  27  /
>
> Procedure created.
>
> SQL>
> ```

Now, Let's test it:

> ```
> SQL> variable rc refcursor;
> SQL> exec ODD_COLUMNS('EMP',:rc);
>
> PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
>
> SQL> print rc;
>
>     EMP_ID E
> ---------- -
>         10 N
>         20 Y
>
> SQL>
> SQL> exec ODD_COLUMNS('MY_TABLE1',:rc);
>
> PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
>
> SQL> print rc;
>
>         ID    REQ_QTY
> ---------- ----------
>       1001         10
>       1001         20
>       1001         30
>       1002         40
>       1003         10
>       1003         20
>
> 6 rows selected.
>
> SQL>
> ```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

This cannot be done simply, but it is possible using the Oracle data dictionary and some dynamic SQL.

To find out the odd-numbered columns you need to look at the ALL_TAB_COLUMNS view.  Column COLUMN_ID sequences the columns 1,2,3.  So this will find all the odd-numbered columns in the SCOTT.EMP table:

```
select column_name, column_id
from all_tab_columns
where owner = 'SCOTT'
and table_name = 'EMP'
and mod(column_id,2) = 1
order by column_id;
```

This will return something like:

```
COLUMN_NAME  COLUMN_ID
-----------  ---------
EMPNO                1
JOB                  3
HIREDATE             5
COMM                 7
```

We can use the LISTAGG function to make that into a comma-separated list:

```
select listagg(column_name,',') within group (order by column_id) as result
from user_tab_columns
where table_name = 'EMP'
and mod(column_id,2) = 1;

RESULT
------
EMPNO,JOB,HIREDATE,COMM
```

Now we can add to that SQL to generate the select statement you want:

```
select 'select ' || listagg(column_name,',') within group (order by column_id) || ' from ' || table_name as sql
from user_tab_columns
where table_name = 'EMP'
and mod(column_id,2) = 1
group by table_name;

SQL
---
select EMPNO,JOB,HIREDATE,COMM from EMP
```

(Note I had to add a `group by` clause because `table_name` is not being aggregated by LISTAGG).

You could use that SQL within some PL/SQL code to populate a variable `v_sql`, then use the [DBMS_SQL package](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/DBMS_SQL.html) to run it.  But that is a complex topic in itself and I won't go into it here.